# Upload Error - Cannot upload apk file to Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, console, google-play

I have some apps in Google Play for some time but I have not been sending updates for a few months. Now I am trying to send an update but I am getting Upload Error as I upload the apk file. I have tried with another app and also with another computer but the same error occurs. I have been trying to solve this issue for 5 past days but I could not find any related resource or same issue occurring with anybody else. I cannot figure out if the problem is due to the new Google Play Developer Console features or anything else. Any help or suggestion from the community is welcomed. Thank you in advance.

This is how the "Upload new APK to Production" screen looks after I browse-upload the apk.

Upload new APK to Production

Upload failed

UPLOAD ANOTHER APK

Comment: reasons maybe 1. `you are uploading Debug apk` 2. `You are uploading apk without incrementing Version number` 3. `You are uploading some other apk`

Comment: Unfortunately these cannot be the possible reasons. I am uploading the Release apk with version number increment of the true apk file. One interesting thing is if you do any of these, it gives error specifying the error but in my case no explanation of the error is included. I have not seen any error like this for 4 years of my android development journey.

Answer (score 32):

The problem is solved. It seems to be caused by some cookies etc. I have tried uploading my apk in browser's incognito mode and had success.

Comment: Same problem for me. Logout and login back resolved it.

Comment: Not working for me, tried to restart the laptop, cleared cache, using firefox, chrome, normal mode, incognito. everything possible. Any other issue this might be? @Fio

Comment: the problem may be with your apk file @ParthAnjaria

Comment: There was some issue with google console, i contacted their team and later the issue got resolved @Fio

Comment: @Fio how did you contact them?

Comment: Having this issue today as well. Last comment was 2 hours ago, so maybe im not the only one.

Comment: @Maxx yes. Me too. There is issue today. i'm stucked in upload error.

Comment: Yup. I think there is an issue with it today. I am also stuck at the upload processing.

Comment: So I tried again this morning and it just worked. I didn't log out, I didn't even refresh the upload page. Seems like the issue may have been on their side.

Comment: another issue today, maybe/

Answer (score 9):

[Cookies](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) ***are the most general problem creators for every scenarios.***

> If you cleared that while using any kind of log-in and log-out
>   credentials.

**It is working well.**

> Otherwise,please use all time"Incognito private browsing window" that
>   problem can't occurs anymore.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be an issue with cashe

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Firefox seems to be particularly badly behaved with the Google Play Console - even the main account page times out and sits there forever, displaying the spinner. My solution to not being able to upload an APK was to close the tab on Firefox and use another browser (Safari). Upload worked very quickly and was available to release within seconds.

Answer (score -2):

check numbers dots prefix suffix package name spelling punctuation on gradle page,excat keystore passwords dont check tik box  export encrypt  new key everytime keep safe your first key if lost contact console page help or chat