# Is there a way to make the Unity DebugKey into a non Debug key?

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

I have a game on the Play Store, recently i wanted to make an update to it. So i built my Game and uploaded it but Google Play gave me an error that says that i can't upload with a debug key. I made a new key to fix this but because i originally uploaded it with the debug key the keys didn't match. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a bug in the Play store. The upload validation process got stricter recently, and is checking for debug keys more thoroughly. But it doesn't exclude apps which already have debug keys as their upload key.

The bug will be fixed soon. However, it sounds like you use Google Play Signing, which is great, it gives you a solution. Follow [the instructions on this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) for contacting Google Play support for changing your upload key.

Comment: Thank you but i don't think i can upload soon, i uploaded my project to onedrive and when i downloaded it again something broke :(

Answer (score -1):

**Please make sure with your old Debug-key**.

> Do not create and change the new one.

**Because , it is affecting your game-application in google-play and removed from it.**

***[Terms and Conditions applied]***

> So,please update your application with origional key which ever you
>   created and used FIRST-TIME.

Comment: @FriederMüller please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44353502/upload-error-cannot-upload-apk-file-to-google-play-developer-console/51853263#51853263